# Hot to get the status code of a shell command?

Tags: c, unix, process, fork, waitpid

I am trying to get the status code of a shell command in C(echo is 0,cat/proc/1/mem is 13 and so on), but I cannot wrap my head around on how to do it.
I have tried :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if(pid==0) {
        execl("/home/rares/Documents/OS/Lab5/testex.c","bin/sh","cat/proc/1/mem",NULL);
    }
    int status;
    waitpid(pid,&status,0);
    if(WIFEXITED(status)) {
        int exit_stauts=WEXITSTATUS(status);
        printf("Exist status is %d\n",exit_stauts );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    int x=system("cat/proc/1/mem");
    if(x==0) {
        printf("command succeeded\n");
        printf("exit status is %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(x));
    } else if ( WIFSIGNALED(x)) {
        printf("command termianted with signal%d\n",WTERMSIG(x));
    } else if(WIFEXITED(x)) {
        printf("command existed %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(x));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but they do not seem to work
Maybe my approaches are  completely off but I couldn't find anything apart from the fact that I should be using `fork()`, `waitpid()` and `execl()`. Also, if any of my functions are not used correctly please let me know.

Comment: Do either of those commands work when typed?

Comment: @stark yes, hello world does but the other one does no, yet the echo one does not work in the program

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the problem is that your `execl` fails (there is probably no executable of the name `/home/rares/Documents/OS/Lab5/testex.c`. Then the child executes a `waitpid(0` which waits for its own children that does not exists and terminates with return code 0. The parent then, executes the sequence, waits for the child which terminated in success with 0. YOu can observe a better behaviour with:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if(pid==0) {
        execl("/home/rares/Documents/OS/Lab5/testex.c","bin/sh","cat/proc/1/mem",NULL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int status;
    waitpid(pid,&status,0);
    if(WIFEXITED(status)) {
        int exit_stauts=WEXITSTATUS(status);
        printf("Exist status is %d\n",exit_stauts );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the second case, the command does not exists `cat/proc/1/mem`.

Comment: I have managed to fix the path but the problem is that I do not get what I need from the program, I'm guessing that the approach used is not correct but I'm not quite sure how to get what I want(status code) and this just gives the exit code.